# How to fill grid view length wise?

Tags: android, gridview

I am using Grid View to display details of 24 students. According to data provided, after I get the name of all students, I will get DOB then address and then ph_no. Is it possible to fill the grid view column wise (i.e. top to bottom and then move to next row) ? Grid View is vertically scrollable.

Structure of my layout will be similar to structure given below:

```
     name  DOB  address  ph_no
  1   A
  2   B
  3   C
  .   .
  .   .
  .   .
  24  Z
```

Answer (score 0):

Create two layouts, one for the header and another one for the grid items. Use weights to fit width, setting the same values for header and it corresponding row field.

Comment: How to fill data top -> bottom instead of default left -> right in grid view ?

Comment: You should not use a gridview but a listview for that.